# Typecasting String to Error is unpredictable

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

This I a strange one. In a project I'm working on I have the following code

`let stuff = "stuff" as Error`

This seems to compile with out any problems but looks somewhat stange to me.

I created an empty project with same swift version (4.2). In this test project the same line gives me

> 'String' is not convertible to 'Error'; did you mean to use 'as!' to
>   force downcast?

which is kind of what I expected in the first place. This made me believe that the code compiles in the original project because some dependency is doing som kind of magic, so added all the dependencies to my test project, but this changed nothing - it still won't compile.

I'm trying hard to wrap my head around what's going on here, but I'm stuck and need your help to figure it out. Could it be some kind of compiler flag? or is there a dependency that does som kind of magic with the `as` keyword? How can I figure out what's going on here?

Comment: Check your old project for a `extension String: Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add below code in your new project.

```
extension String: Error {}
```

It allows throwing a string as an Error

```
func someFunction() throws {
    throw "some message" 
}    
do {
    try someFunction() 
} catch let errorMessage {
    print(errorMessage) 
}
```

Comment: You were right, there was an extension on String making it conforming to Error... I have no idea how I missed this. Anyways I actually wanted to prevent this behaviour      so the solution was to delete the extension.